# c# MVC Post to web API coming over with all null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to post a model to a web API. The post makes it there but all the values are null. The Gets are working fine and the id's are passing over in the url. It seems that trying to pass content isn't working. The code below is what I'm using. Thanks in advance!

```
public async Task<string> UpdateAddress(UpdateAddressModel model)
{
    string text = "";

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            var PayLoad = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(PayLoad, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var Response = await client.PostAsync("https://url/api/user/EditAddress/", content);

            Response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var response = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return response;            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        text = ex.Message;
    }
    return text;
}
```

I've tried using HpptRequest Headers and mapping the model manually but the information doesn't make it to the api. And I tried adding the FromBody tag to the api.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where are you filling UpdateAddressModel?

Comment: And can you show the code for it?

Comment: The model comes in populated. When I step through it you can see it get serialized to the Payload variable.

Comment: Then when do you see it as empty? Can you show the API side please?

Comment: @Abdelkrim I know I said I tried this but I added the [FromBody] tag to the API controller and now data is coming over in the model. I'm not sure why it didn't work before. Thanks for taking the time to help me with this!

Comment: Hows your API controller signature looks like? Can you include that within your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried using HpptRequest Headers and mapping the model manually
> but the information doesn't make it to the api. And I tried adding the
> FromBody tag to the api.

Based on your shared code snippet and descriptions, I have tried to simulate your scenario and I have successfully send model value to API controller using your cmethod.

According to my test, I have followed below steps:

Demo Model:

I have used following model in order to bind demo value:

```
public class UpdateAddressModel
    {
        public string? Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Sending Request Using UpdateAddress  Method:

```
UpdateAddressModel requestMdoel = new UpdateAddressModel();
requestMdoel.Email = "mytestemail@outlook.com";
var callMethod = UpdateAddress(requestMdoel);
```

Web API Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("EditAddress")]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] UpdateAddressModel model)
        {
            return Ok(model.Email);
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Take aways:** According to my test it seems that your UpdateAddress method signature is correct. However, make sure your web API defination and request model is correct and most importantly, double check if you are passing your request model value accordingly.